# Proving the limit (epsilon criterion)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_n:= \frac{1}{n+a}$ prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$. Of course that is obvious due to the direct comparison test with the series $\frac{1}{n}$. However I need to prove it directly with the epsilon  criterion.

What I have done: $\epsilon > 0$, then there is a $n_0 > \frac{1-a\epsilon }{\epsilon}$

$|\frac{1}{n+a}-0|=|\frac{1}{n+a}|=\frac{1}{n+a} \leq \frac{1}{n_0+a} < \frac{1}{\frac{1-\epsilon a}{\epsilon}+a}=\epsilon$

Can I argue like this?

Comment: yes, looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- The letter $x$ becomes $a$ after some time.
- You claim than $\left|\frac1{n+a}\right|=\frac1{n+a}$. Why? You are not assuming that $a\geqslant0$. You should choose $n_0$ such that$$n_0\geqslant\max\left\{-a,\frac{1-a\varepsilon}\varepsilon\right\}$$and then to say that $n\geqslant n_0$.

Comment: thank you so much. I corrected it, it should have been a the whole time